# Out-File behaves strange when throwing an exception

Tags: powershell, exception, try-catch

## What arose the question

I tried to run the following:

```
try {
 $Content | Out-File "SomePath.txt" -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
  echo "Error!!!"
}

echo "Still here!"
```

## What i caught (mentally caught that is...)

From what i caught, there are 2 types of exceptions in Powershell - Terminating, and non-terminating. 
[From here](https://www.pdq.com/blog/error-handling-with-powershell/#:%7E:text=After%20the%20%2DErrorAction%20is%20set,runs%20into%20a%20terminating%20error.&text=In%20this%20script%2Dblock%2C%20we,so%20it%20would%20not%20continue):

> There are two types of exceptions: terminating and non-terminating. Terminating exceptions stop the
> running script. Non-terminating exceptions just write to the error pipeline.

And in order to catch an exception in a `try-catch` block, the exception must be terminating. 
So you need either to set the `$ErrorActionPreference` to `Stop`, or to run the cmdlet
with the `-ErrorAction Stop` flag. 
So, the following code will terminate the script:

```
try {
 Get-Content "Path-Doesnt-Exist" -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
 echo "Dang!"
}
echo "Still here!"
```

will output `Dang!`

whereas, the following code:

```
 Get-Content "Path-Doesnt-Exist"
 echo "Still here!"
```

will output that red error, and then `Still here!`.

So far so good!

## The problem

When i ran the first snippet of code (with the `Out-File`), i noticed that the
`catch` block was executed. output:

```
Error!!!
Still here!
```

Which is fine. 
But then i noticed that if i run it without the `-ErrorAction Stop`, i get the same result, 
which was suprising. But then i found out that it's a terminating exception, so you don't need 
to set the `ErrorAction` to `Stop`, and not only that you don't need, it doesn't take any effect also.

Then i found out that if i run

```
$Content | Out-File "Path-Doesnt-Exist" -ErrorAction Stop
echo "Still here!"
```

(And i expect the script to stop executing)
It prints:

```
<some red error>
Still here!
```

## Finally

What is going on? If the exception that is thrown from the `Out-File` cmdlet 
is terminating, then why is the script not terminated when it's not 
in a `try-catch` block???

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following your question correctly, this will cause a command terminating exception, but not a script terminating exception.  Command terminating can be caught by try, but when it's not caught the script still continues. The command just might not finish its own actions.  Although it's hard to come up with an example of that.

```
try {get-content text | out-file FolderNotExist\out } catch {'no' }

no
```

```
# out-file can't output to an array of paths
# set-content would not have a terminating exception
get-content text | out-file FolderNotExist\out
echo "Still here!"

out-file : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\js\foo\FolderNotExist\out'.
At C:\Users\js\foo\try.ps1:1 char:20
+ get-content text | out-file FolderNotExist\out
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Still here!
```

```
# out2 still gets created
get-content text | set-content FolderNotExist\out,out2
```

Comment: I think yes. Can you explain the notion of "Script terminating" vs "Command terminating" exceptions?

Comment: A terminating exception that is not handled inside a try/catch block will cause the script to terminate. The try/catch blocks protect against the whole script from terminating and allow you to decide what to do.

So a terminating exception could either be command terminating or script terminating. It depends on your try/catch blocks.

Comment: @JoshWright Confusingly, it's a thing, shown by what out-file does.  Some exceptions that try/catch handles won't stop a script if the try/catch isn't there.  https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583 `1/0` is the classic example.  Powershell is like an english muffin with a lot of nooks and crannies.